# Measure Performance for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands on DB2

Tags: performance, db2, insert, jdbc, iseries

I have a DB2 database with a table for daily transactions, which is cleared to a history table at the end of the day, every day.

I insert rows to this table via java-JDBC INSERT commands and they usually take less than a second to complete but sometimes (I'm still not sure what is the pattern) it can take up to a minute to complete the INSERT command and since I don't have a timeout configured on the JDBC driver, it waits until the command is completed and then carries on.

These INSERT commands are executed thousands of times per day but this only happens on about 5 or 10 of them almos every day. The table has some indexes and a trigger attached on AFTER INSERT event.

Is there any tool or technique I can use to measure what is taking so long to execute on my INSERT command? I want to know if it is the indexes, the trigger or, for any reason, the query itself.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: The version is V6R1M0, on an AS400

Comment: The database on System i is tightly integrated with the operating system. You might be able to get some hints from the system monitoring toos, as explained [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzajq/rzajqnavmon.htm?lang=en).

Comment: I would also look into any locking views to see why things are waiting.

Answer (score -2):

I guess it's a locking issue.

While such inserts take so long use admin view below. The column HLD_CURRENT_STMT_TEXT shows the blocker statement (what cause the insert took so long):

```
db2 select * from SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS
```

Comment: You sure `SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS` exists in the IBM i 6.1 database?

Comment: oops, my bad!! it exists on DB2 luw.